# gridster not using callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

i have been trying to tinker with the callback function of my gridster. all i want it to do is call back the location of my grid, then using jquerys load function , pass it to another page to store and save the information. However i either return an error or nothing upon using this method. current code is as follows

```
    var gridster =  $(".gridster").gridster({
widget_margins: [1, 1],
widget_base_dimensions: [318, 184],
serialize_params: function ($w, wgd) {
return {
id: wgd.el[0].id,
col: wgd.col,
row: wgd.row,
size_y: wgd.size_y,
size_x: wgd.size_x
}
},
widget_selector: ".draggable",
draggable: {

    stop: function(e, ui, $widget) {
        alert('hello world');
    }
}


,
draggable: {
       handle: ".headertitle"
    }




}).data('gridster');
gridster.enable();
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You will need to sahre what is happening on the Page _mydash_save_grid.cfm_. In cases like this firegbug or Chrome Dev tools or Charles can tell you a good deal of information - what's passed and what is passed back.

Comment: well i was putting in an alert after the stop function, and its not firing, so it has nothing to do with the mydash_save_grid.cfm, its somewhere in the actual event thats calling it

Comment: Why is this tagged as 'ColdFusion'?

Comment: originally had a jquery load command that passed to coldfusion file, updated version took out load command to show that not even the stop trigger is working, never removed tag

Comment: You would still need to specify that you have verified (through some client side tool) that CF is _not_ or _is_ receiving the data and returning what you expect. Otherwise us server side guys sit here and wonder. :)

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem, was using the defining variable draggable twice, which was canceling out the stop function, moved them into one setup, solved problem

```
    draggable: {

    stop: function(e, ui, $widget) {
        alert('hello world');
    }
}


,
draggable: {
       handle: ".headertitle"
    }
```

edited to

```
    draggable: {
    handle: ".headertitle"
    stop: function(e, ui, $widget) {
        alert('hello world');
    }
}
```